# How disable appear birthday events on outlook?

Tags: outlook, add-in

I  add some contactItems on Outlook and fill field "birthday" than  appear birthday appointmentItem in Calendar. Can  I change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. I read that you can at least access the associated `AppointmentItem` for the newly created `ContactItem` somehow, in order to delete it. However, I did not find the appropriate property.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6b481f74-8422-46d4-90a9-a5860dcb98b5/to-avoid-automatic-birthday-calendar-event-creation-when-creating-contact?forum=outlookdev